SQL syntax -- 001003 (42000) Error executing Snowflake SQL from Glue
I need to execute following SQL block from Glue but I keep getting the error Exception: There is an error with the SQL syntax -- 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 26 unexpected ''. When I run the same sql directly in snowflake it works fine but not able to do so successfully via glue. Am I missing something here?
USE ROLE <role>;
USE WAREHOUSE <warehouse>;
USE SCHEMA <schema>;
ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG = '<Query_tag>';
BEGIN
LET RCD_CHK number := (1);
IF (RCD_CHK =1) THEN
RETURN RCD_CHK;
ELSE
LET var1 string := (2);
return var1;
end if;
end;

